# Can object be customer and user in a inheritance design

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have a design problem here. I have a three clases.

--Father

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "Persona", schema = "dbo", catalog = "cxc")
Class Person
```

Child´s

```
Class User extends Person
Class Customer extends Person
```

I hava a doubt if this design is the correct to my aplication because de customer can acces to the aplicacation to view the estate acount, and make payments.

And I dont know if where posible  if the customer cant be User at the same time and  maintaining integrity in the data(because is only one person in real life.)

Thank´s in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only extend from one class in Java.  However, you can implement many interfaces.  This means that with your design, User and Customer cannot be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Customer should be an interface instead, and User can implement Customer. This would allow you to have Users behave like users and customers (which if I understand you correctly is what you want), and if you wanted to limit to just the customer portion simply reference the object via it's interface like this:

```
Customer customer = (Customer)/* the user object. */
```

This would mean User's class definition would look like this:

```
class User extends Person implements Customer {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in Java only single inheritance is allowed.

About design what I would do is:

**class User extends Person**

and then depending how much **Customer** is different from **User** you can skip the Customer class and add additional property of user type in the User class.
It can be for example an enum:

```
enum UserType {
  Customer,
  User,
  Boss,
  // etc...
}
```

However if there is big business logic behind the Customer and it must be clear difference between users and customers then there is nothing wrong with you design.

Answer (score 0):

From your description: `de customer can acces to the aplicacation to view the estate acount, and make payments`. It seems to me that `view the estate acount` and `make payments` are *privileges* that customers have and *customer* itself is a kind of role.

I'm not sure why you want to model it into *Customer* and *User* in the first place, maybe some background on the application will help here.